# show/hide the content by clicking button

Tags: android

Hi I want to show/hide the content by clicking button. I am having a problem to hide the content by clicking button.

**Here is my code for hiding the content**

```
private boolean visible; 
protected Button SearchButton;
private void Toggle(){
if(visible=false){
    DishButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    SpoonButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    cupButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    FridgeButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

else {
    DishButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    SpoonButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cupButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    FridgeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    visible=true;
}         
}
```

Comment: the error message is    unexpected token foe DishButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  and private method toggle is never used

Comment: What problem are you specifically having?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(visible=false)
```

is not gonna work!

Use `if(visible==false)`.

Note that you can use `View.GONE` to hide the content and free the empty space.

Comment: the problem is,  the error message is private method toggle is never used

Answer (score 0):

From your comments and question it seems like

1. You have not put any listener to your button.
2. You have written `=` in place of `==`.
3. You have user `View.INVISILE` which will permanently hide the element it will not come back. SO use `View.GONE`
4. You have some logic flaw in case of handling visible/invisible.
5. You have not initialized visible boolean with true because as first time you are showing all the buttons so it should be true.

**So possible solution is**

In your `onCreate()` method add

```
visible=true; 
SearchButton.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener()
{   
 public void onClick(View v)
{
    Toggle();
}

});
```

And make the Toggle method look like

```
private void Toggle(){
if(visible==true){
DishButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
SpoonButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
cupButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
FridgeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
visible=false;
}

else {
DishButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
SpoonButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
cupButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
FridgeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
visible=true;
}         
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting an error "Unexpected token".

Comment: post your full class. @tani

Comment: can i ask you another question?                                                                      For android app, If the content is not in the search request, then how to show message "Sorry, we could not find your request".

Comment: You should ask another question not in comment. This is a rule in stackoverflow and we cant ignore it. Please ask your question as a question. I will  try to follow  and help. btw if the answer worked for you you can accept the answer so that people can get help in fututre from this thread. @tani